# C++03 Determining Begining of a segment

Tags: c++03

I am working on a 32 bit embedded system where size of each segment of flash is 0x200.  I am trying to build a function to change values in a segment, so the function looks like this:

```
unsigned int cBSL_flash_set_array(const uint8_t* src_ptr,
                              uint8_t* dest_ptr,
                              unsigned int len,
                              const unsigned int seg_size) {
//  .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
uint32_t mask = ~(seg_size - 1);

uint8_t* seg_start = dest_ptr & mask;     // Mask it
```

}

Unfortunately the compiler will not pass this, saying that:

```
/work/c1202-firmware/msp430-OTP/otp/cBSL_hw_layer.c:229:37: error: invalid operands of types ‘uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}’ and ‘uint32_t {aka unsigned int}’ to binary ‘operator&’
 uint8_t* seg_start = dest_ptr & mask;     // Mask it
```

Any ideas how to mask it?

EDIT:

This seems to work but it is lots of step for just masking:

```
union Pointer {
   uint32_t loc;
   uint8_t* loc_ptr;
};

Pointer SegStart;                    // declare Pointer Union

SegStart.loc_ptr = dest_ptr;         // Set to destination

uint32_t rem = SegStart.loc & (seg_size - 1);  // figure out remainder

SegStart.loc -= rem;                 // start of segment
```

Comment: have you tried casting?

Comment: Tried casting, compiler wont let me complains about loss of precision.

Comment: Could you do this using an array-based approach? Treat the segment as an array of uint_8's and index them, rather than having to modify the uint_8* start pointer?